# Get method it is working in other function but in another I cannot see the get method TS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am changing some data in TS files and I have created two variables, in the first the get method it is working but in the second not, I don't need anymore the first because I am changing the complete code, how can I use get in another way.
I am trying in the TestProdcutIds to have the get method
Here is my code.

Here the get method it is working oke and everything works as excepted.

```
getCustomersPurchasedProduct(): Customer[] {
    return this.customers.toArray().filter(customer => customer.purchasedProductIds.get(this.selectedProduct.id));
  }
```

Here I cannot put the get dataI just see

```
.concat
.copyWithin
.entries.
.values
.filter
.reduce and some other methods.


CustomersPurchasedProduct(): Customer[] {
   return  this.customers.toArray().filter(customer => customer.TestProductIds.(this.selectedProduct.id));
  }
```

Here is what is in the interface of the Customer.

```
export interface Customer {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  purchasedProductIds: Map<string, number>;
  TestProductIds: string[];
```

Comment: are you trying to use `.get` on `TestProductIds` or `purchasedProductIds` ?

Comment: in the TestProductIds because in the purchasedProductIds is there

Comment: TestProductIds is an array, so there is no `.get`

Comment: What can I change there to have the .get ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your checking whether a specific value is contained in an array, [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) should do the trick:

```
CustomersPurchasedProduct(): Customer[] {
  return this.customers.toArray().filter(customer =>
      customer.TestProductIds.indexOf(this.selectedProduct.id) >= 0);
}
```

Or you can use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (depending on the ECMAScript version you're targeting):

```
CustomersPurchasedProduct(): Customer[] {
  return this.customers.toArray().filter(customer =>
      customer.TestProductIds.includes(this.selectedProduct.id));
}
```

Comment: I am having this error in the console.

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Comment: Then you have no `TestProductIds` value for your customer, so you first need to check if the property exists. `customer.testProductIds && customerTestProductIds.indexOf(...)`

Comment: Yeah you are right the list of testProductIds in empty but in the purchasedProductIds I have 3 arrays.

Comment: It would not throw an error if it the array is empty, only if it was null, undefined, not an array, etc.

Comment: What do you suggest me to do in this case ?

Comment: I have made your answer as accepted while I think this would  help me